# How login a user on desktop screen using ssh

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I wanted to be able to login users on their desktop using ssh. I've a lot of clients and I want to log all of them in using ssh from the server. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. How can this be accomplished?

**Edit:** in order to clarify a bit more:
Let's say I'm in computer A. I use an ssh connection to computer B. I want to login computer B in such a way that a person sitting behind computer B see the computer logged in as if he himself logged in manually.
I mean, I want to do something so that it'll be exactly as if a user sat behind computer B, entered the password and logged in.

Comment: i tried it. it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you mean you want to log users into their accounts on the gui through an ssh connection? If so please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes. I've edited my post.

Comment: Read `man ssh` and `man sshd`. Would `ssh -X` help? If you want to run programs on the remote system using your local keyboard and displaying on the remote system, or something else, please explain.

Comment: No,  I want to login a user to the system and open a program firefox on the monitor so when user sits behind the computer, there will be no need to login or open the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of searching in Google and trying different things I ended up with two ways to do this:

1. First make your user auto-login by creating file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with this content:

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   autologin-user=YOUR_USERNAME
   autologin-user-timeout=0
   user-session=ubuntu
   greeter-session=unity-greeter
   ```

   <sup>(for more information [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](/q/51086))</sup>

   Then you must restart lightdm using the command:

   ```
   service lightdm restart
   ```

   This results in lightdm logging automatically using your username. Now you can remove the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in order to disable auto-login for your user again.
2. You must first stop lightdm using the command:

   ```
   service lightdm stop
   ```

   then you must use the following command to start an x-session manually:

   ```
   su - YOUR_USERNAME "startx -- :0 vt7" &
   ```

   this command starts a new x-session logged in with your username on tty7, the default tty for lightdm. the `&` sign at the end detaches this process.

   Note 1: if you receive an error saying

   > X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.

   you must edit the file located at `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and set `allowed_users` to `anybody`. After the start of the x-session you can return it to the previous value(normally `console`) for security reasons.

   Note 2: If your x-session is showing only the desktop and not the unity panels, try removing files `.config` and `.cache` located at home folder of your user.

If you know any better ways or some improvement you might think is useful please share it here. Thank you.